# R ReadHTMLTable Pro Football Refrence Team Offense

Tags: r

I am trying to get the "Team Offense" table into R. I have tried multiple techniques and I cannot seem to get it to work. It looks like R is only reading the first two tables. The link is below.

https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/index.htm

This is what I have tried...

```
   library(XML)
TeamData = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/index.htm'TeamData = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/index.htm'
URL = TeamData
URLdata = getURL(URL)
table = readHTMLTable(URLdata, stringsAsFactors=F, which = 5)
```

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688757/extracting-table-data-from-a-website-using-r/53689067?noredirect=1#comment94456794_53689067

Comment: Skeptical of answering scraping questions. Anyway take a  look at the `rvest` package.

Answer (score 1):

Scraping Sports Reference sites can be tricky but they are great sources:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

link <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/index.htm"

doc <- GET(link)

cont <- content(doc, "text") %>% 
  gsub(pattern = "<!--\n", "", ., fixed = TRUE) %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_nodes(".table_outer_container table") %>% 
  html_table()

# Team Offense table is the fifth one
df <- cont[[5]]
```